# I can't make a non root user get sudo

Tags: ssh, command

I'm trying to use sudo as NON ROOT user, so i have made some research on internet and i have found that the user (in this case creaz) needs to be added to the sudoers file.

So i did [root@vps1484 ~]$ visudo as root and i have added :

```
creaz     ALL=(ALL)     ALL
```

When i'm connected to creaz@creaz.pro via the ssh when i type sudo i'm getting :

```
[root@vps1484 ~]$ su creaz
creaz@creaz.pro [~]# sudo
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
```

If i do :

```
creaz@creaz.pro [~]# ls -l `which sudo`
---x--x--x 1 root root 123832 Aug 13  2015 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

Did i miss something ?

Updated:

```
[root@vps1484 ~]$ stat /usr/bin/sudo
  File: `/usr/bin/sudo'
  Size: 123832          Blocks: 248        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: a7a0b651h/2812327505d   Inode: 149272      Links: 1
Access: (4111/---s--x--x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-05-27 02:00:09.643651919 +1000
Modify: 2016-05-11 09:13:13.000000000 +1000
Change: 2016-05-27 01:11:02.486593149 +1000
[root@vps1484 ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Sudo executable needs to have suid bit set:

```
$ ll `which sudo`
---s--x--x. 1 root root 139024 Nov  5  2015 /usr/bin/sudo
```

You can achieve that by running

```
chmod 4111 `which sudo`
```

under the `root` account.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. i tried the chmod but still the same issue. creaz@creaz.pro [~]# ls -l `which sudo`
---s--x--x 1 root root 123832 Aug 13  2015 /usr/bin/sudo*
creaz@creaz.pro [~]# sudo
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?
creaz@creaz.pro [~]#

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `stat /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: It looks ok. I don't see a reason why it should not work. Maybe interesting would be to hear what OS are you using.